# Complex many-to-many searching

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, many-to-many

I have four tables:

- `Pages` stores search options to drive a set of search pages:

  ```
  pk_id, title, country, location
  ```
- `Pages_Types` stores zero or more real estate types for each page:

  ```
  fk_id, listing_type
  ```
- `Listings` stores real estate listings:

  ```
  pk_ref, title, country, location
  ```
- `Listings_Types` stores 1 or more types for each real estate listing:

  ```
  fk_ref, listing_type
  ```

---

A webpage passes `Pages.pk_id` to a stored procedure that looks up the search options and returns the `Listings` that match.

There are several hundred pages with very variable search options. A page may specify a country but not a location, or specifies both, sometimes it has listing_types and sometimes not.

**Page A**

- pk_id = A
- American Houses and Apartments
- Country = United States
- Location = Texas

Pages_Types:

- fk_id = A, listing_type = House
- fk_id = A, listing_type = Apartment

---

**Page B**

- pk_id = B
- Australian Real Estate
- Country = Australia
- Location = null
- Page B has no Pages_Types records because all listing types should be shown

---

**Page C**

- pk_id = C
- Australian Apartments
- Country = Australia
- Location = null

Pages_Types:

- fk_id = C, listing_type = Apartment

---

**Listing 1**

- pk_ref = 123
- title = 3 bedroom family home
- Country = United States
- Location = Texas

Listing_Types:

- fk_ref = 123, listing_type = House
- fk_ref = 123, listing_type = Singe Family House

**Listing 2**

- pk_ref = 456
- title = 2 bedroom apartment
- Country = Australia
- Location = New South Wales

Listing_Types:

- fk_ref = 456, listing_type = Apartment

**Listing 3**

- pk_ref = 789
- title = 3 bedroom house
- Country = Australia
- Location = New South Wales

Listing_Types:

- fk_ref = 456, listing_type = House

**Listing 4**

- pk_ref = 012
- title = Warehouse
- Country = United States
- Location = New York

Listing_Types:

- fk_ref = 012, listing_type = Warehouse

---

For years I used a stored procedure where Pages and Listings only had one listing_type each in the main record. I have recently changed my db to allow Pages and Listings to have more than one listing_type to better describe them.

I am struggling to amend my stored procedure for this many-to-many and variably null dataset.

If the Page specifies listing_type(s) then only Listings with that listing_type should be returned. But if the page does not specify listing_type(s) then all Listings should be returned that match the Country and Location options.

1. Page A should show Listing 1 but not Listing 4 (American houses and
   apartments)
2. Page B should show listings 2 and 3 (all Australian real
   estate)
3. Page C should show listing 2 (Australian apartments)

Here is as far as I have got:

```
SELECT l.pk_ref,l.Location,l.Country,lt.PropertyType FROM Listings l
JOIN Listing_Types lt ON l.pk_ref = lt.fk_ref
JOIN Pages_Types pt ON lt.PropertyType = pt.PropertyType
JOIN Pages p ON p.pk_LPID = pt.fk_LPID
WHERE l.pk_id = 'A' AND 
l.Country = p.Country AND
l.Location = p.Geo_Location
```

I've tried various different JOINS but either the results are incorrect or no records are returned.

Comment: Here's a [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/3oT1C680) of your data

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you are looking for.

The case statement in the where clause will look for the Country and when @Country is not null, then match on the variable value.  Otherwise it will match Country in the table to itself.  Which is the same as saying Where 1=1  it is always true.

```
DECLARE @Country varchar(30) = null
DECLARE @Location varchar(30) = null
DECLARE @Listing_Type VARCHAR(30) = NULL

SELECT @Country = Country,
@Location = Location,
@Listing_Type = Listing_Type 
FROM Pages WHERE pk_id = 'A'


SELECT * 
FROM Listings 
WHERE Country = CASE WHEN @Country IS NOT NULL THEN @Country ELSE Country END
AND Location = CASE WHEN @Location IS NOT NULL THEN @Location ELSE Location END
AND Listing_Type = CASE WHEN @Listing_Type IS NOT NULL THEN @Listing_Type ELSE Listing_Type END
```

The other way to do this would be with dynamic SQL and doing an If variable is NULL do not add it to the where clause in your dynamic SQL.

Comment: I now have four tables - Pages and Listings now have sub tables to store multiple listing_types for each, and joining these is what I'm struggling with. ie. I am no longer matching one type to one type

Comment: Ok, looks like your original query/question was updated.  If you need to do logic similar you can do it in a JOIN as well with the same case logic I have above.

Comment: If you have multiple tables and multiple/different logic you want to run you can create a SELECT for each set of logic and either do a UNION ALL with the multiple selects.  Or insert the results from each SELECT into a temp/stage table (probably better performance) and then remove dupes on the final temp table.